Unable to see logs in NewRelic using opentelemetry-dotnet
When the ASP.NET application is starting up, some logs are sent and they are visible in NewRelic. But when the application handles an http request, the logs sent through ILogger<T> never appear in NewRelic.
I have the OTEL_DIAGNOSTICS.json file, but no errors are written. ConsoleExporter works flawlessly. I can see traces normally. In NewRelic nothing appears in NrIntegrationError collection.
What am I doing wrong? It seems NewRelic only shows logs that are not correlated with traces and spans.
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(builder => builder.AddService(Otel.ServiceName, serviceVersion: Otel.ServiceVersion))
    .WithLogging(logging => logging
        .AddConsoleExporter()
        .AddOtlpExporter(otlp =>
        {
            otlp.Endpoint = new Uri($"{_otelEndpoint}/v1/logs");
            otlp.Headers = $"api-key={_otelApiKey}";
            otlp.Protocol = _otelProtocol; // Using Http/Protobuf
        }), options =>
        {
            options.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
            options.IncludeScopes = true;
            options.ParseStateValues = true;
        })
    .WithTracing(tracing => tracing
        .AddSource(Otel.ServiceName)
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddRedisInstrumentation()
        .AddAWSInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter(options =>
        {
            options.Endpoint = new Uri($"{_otelEndpoint}/v1/traces");
            options.Headers = $"api-key={_otelApiKey}";
            options.Protocol = _otelProtocol;
        }))
    .WithMetrics(metrics => metrics
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter(options =>
        {
            options.Endpoint = new Uri($"{_otelEndpoint}/v1/metrics");
            options.Headers = $"api-key={_otelApiKey}";
            options.Protocol = _otelProtocol;
        }));


I cannot reproduce your problem. In case it helps, here's a more complete example. I've simplified it a bit removing parts from your example that I do not believe are relevant.
csproj file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Program.cs
using OpenTelemetry.Logs;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var _otelEndpoint = "https://otlp.nr-data.net";
var _otelProtocol = OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
var _otelApiKey = "my-api-key";

builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(builder => builder.AddService("MyService"))
    .WithLogging(logging => logging
        .AddOtlpExporter(otlp =>
        {
            otlp.Endpoint = new Uri($"{_otelEndpoint}/v1/logs");
            otlp.Headers = $"api-key={_otelApiKey}";
            otlp.Protocol = _otelProtocol;
        }), options =>
        {
            options.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
            options.IncludeScopes = true;
            options.ParseStateValues = true;
        })
    .WithTracing(tracing => tracing
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter(options =>
        {
            options.Endpoint = new Uri($"{_otelEndpoint}/v1/traces");
            options.Headers = $"api-key={_otelApiKey}";
            options.Protocol = _otelProtocol;
        }))
    .WithMetrics(metrics => metrics
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter(options =>
        {
            options.Endpoint = new Uri($"{_otelEndpoint}/v1/metrics");
            options.Headers = $"api-key={_otelApiKey}";
            options.Protocol = _otelProtocol;
        }));

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () =>
{
    app.Logger.LogInformation("Info");
    return "Hello";
});

app.Run();

When I exercise the app I see logs in New Relic as expected.

Logs are also correctly correlated with the trace/span they occurred during.

